# Is there any alternative to DHCPv6?

Tags: ipv6, dhcp

Understanding that IPv6 gives you the advantage having an autoconfigured link local address that can be used for communicating within the network but still with the restriction of being unable to route it inside the network or communicate only within the same interface , assignment of a unique local address still needing a DHCP server for assigning ip dynamically . What I am curious about is, is there any alternative over DHCP to dynamically assign a unique local address to any device that connects to the network?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radvd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you mean by "dynamically assign," [stateless address autoconfiguration](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4862) could be an alternative.  In this configuration, a router will broadcast its presence on a network segment and hosts will use the communicated network prefix to autonomously create one or more IP addresses for themselves -- they do not request any addresses from a central authority, which contrasts with the DHCPv6 mechanism.